# Swing desktop application. AWTEventMulticaster error

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

I have a Java Swing desktop application. When I search from database I get this exception.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError    at 
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)   at 
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
```

Sample code:

```
      textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                  @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {                     
                        searchTableData(textField);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        searchTableData(textField);
                    }
              });

public void searchTableData(JTextField tf){
     try
     {      
        this.panelWares.calculate = false;
        String searchVal = tf.getText();
        if(searchVal.equals("")){ 
            this.panelWares.paramsRefresh = 
                   new HashMap<String, NamedParameter>();
            this.panelWares.refreshTable(0);
            //tf.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        String colName = tf.getName();
        this.panelWares.paramsRefresh = new HashMap<String, NamedParameter>();
        this.panelWares.paramsRefresh.put(colName, 
         new NamedParameter(searchVal, "string", "like_both")); 
        this.panelWares.refreshTable(0);     
        this.panelWares.calculate = true;
     }
     catch(Exception er){
         er.printStackTrace();
         UtilsStoreDepo.showMessage("Xeta:" + er.getMessage());
     }
    }

    //  paramsRefresh = Hashmap
    public boolean refreshTable(int selRow) {                                   
        model.execute(connection, table, paramsRefresh);        
        if(cc <= 1)
         initTable(model);
        cc++;
        table.setModel(model);
        scPane.setViewportView(table);
        int posIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
        Rectangle rect = table.getCellRect(posIndex, 0, true);
        scPane.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible(rect);
        wares_amount = String.valueOf(table.getSelectedValue("amount"));
        return true;
    }


    public void initTable(CustomTableModel model){
        table = new TableWares(model){

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                 int row, int column){
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);


                Object val = getModel().getValueAt(row, column);  
                Object valLimit = getModel().getValueAt(row, column);  
                Object valOrderAmount = getModel().getValueAt(row, column);  

                if(getRowCount() > 0){
                    c.setForeground(Color.BLUE); 
                    c.setFont(c.getFont());

                    for(int i = 0 ; i < table.getColumnsName().length; i++ ){
                        int vCol =  getColumnIndex(table.getColumnsName()[i], table.getColumnsName());
                        if(table.getColumnsResize()[i] == false){
                            if(column == vCol){                          
                                if(isRowSelected(row)) 
                                 c.setForeground(selectionBackground);
                                else
                                 c.setForeground(getBackground());   
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            val = getModel().getValueAt(row, getColumnIndex("amount", table.getColumnsName())); 
                            valLimit = getModel().getValueAt(row, getColumnIndex("amount_limit", table.getColumnsName())); 
                            valOrderAmount = getModel().getValueAt(row, getColumnIndex("order_amount", table.getColumnsName())); 

                            BigDecimal valB = new BigDecimal("0");
                            BigDecimal valLimitB = new BigDecimal("0");

                            if(val != null && !val.equals("") && valLimit != null && !valLimit.equals("")){
                                val = val.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
                                valLimit = valLimit.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
                                valB = new BigDecimal(val.toString());
                                valLimitB = new BigDecimal(valLimit.toString());
                            }

                            if(valB.compareTo(valLimitB) <= 0){
                                c.setForeground(Color.RED);                             
                            }
                            else{
                                c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                            }

                            if(Utils.bd(String.valueOf(valOrderAmount)).compareTo(Utils.BD_SIFIR) > 0 && column == colOrderAmountInd){
                                c.setFont(AllConstants.FONT_ARIAL_BOLD_14);
                                c.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
                                c.setBackground(Color.black);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                c.setFont(getFont());  
                            }

                        }
                    }                     
                }     

                return c;
            }       

        };

        table.setName("wares");
        table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if(table.getRowCount() < 1) return;             
                if(!calculate) return;              
                Utils.plusMinus(table, arg0.getKeyChar(), table.getSelectedRow(), colOrderAmountInd, 0, 10000);             
                if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    editOrGet();
                } 
            }
        });

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {                
                if(table.getRowCount() < 1) return;             
                if(!calculate) return;              
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    editOrGet();
                }
            }

        });

        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

                if(table.getRowCount() < 1) return;

                if(!calculate) return;

                int[] selRow = table.getSelectedRows();
                BigDecimal bdValMiqdar = new BigDecimal("0");
                BigDecimal bdValMD = new BigDecimal("0");
                BigDecimal bdValMX = new BigDecimal("0");



                for(int q = 0; q < selRow.length; q++){ 

                    BigDecimal valMD = new BigDecimal(table.getValue("amount",selRow[q]).toString()).multiply(new BigDecimal(table.getValue("pur_price",selRow[q]).toString()));                  
                    bdValMD = bdValMD.add(valMD);

                    BigDecimal valMX = new BigDecimal(table.getValue("amount",selRow[q]).toString()).multiply(new BigDecimal(table.getValue("sel_price",selRow[q]).toString()));                  
                    bdValMX = bdValMX.add(valMX);

                    BigDecimal valMiqdar = new BigDecimal(table.getValue("amount",selRow[q]).toString());                 
                    bdValMiqdar = bdValMiqdar.add(valMiqdar);

                }
                parent.sumStoreMiqdar = bdValMiqdar.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
                parent.sumStoreMD = bdValMD.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
                parent.sumStoreMX = bdValMX.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: your sample code does not seem to cover the error

Comment: Please provide the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can also reproduce your problem. At least please provide the complete stack trace of your exception, so we can see what's happened.